# Utilizo PHP y mvc y no cargar la vista 404, el archivo controller no lee la función render

Tags: php, mvc, model-view-controller, 404

Estoy usando mvc y php, lo primero que cargo es el login,solo una vista con un h1 que diga login, lo demás lo hago después, este es el archivo app.php

```
<?php

require_once 'controllers/errores.php';

class App{
    function __construct(){

        $url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : null;
        $url = rtrim($url, '/');
        $url = explode('/', $url);
        //http://localhost/MVC/user/updatePhoto -> user/updatePhoto

        if(empty ($url[0])){
            error_log('APP::construct-> no hay controlador especificado');
            $archivoController = 'controllers/login.php';
            require_once $archivoController;
            $controller = new Login();
            $controller->loadModel('login');
            $controller->render();
            return false;
        }

        $archivoController = 'controllers/'.$url[0].'.php';

        if(file_exists($archivoController)){
            require_once $archivoController;

            $controller = new $url[0];
            $controller->loadModel($url[0]);

            if(isset($url[1])){
                if(method_exists($controller, $url[1])){
                    if(isset($url[2])){
                        // No de parámetros
                        $nparam = count($url) - 2;
                        // Arreglo de parámetros
                        $params = [];

                        for($i = 0; $i< $nparam; $i++){
                            array_push($params, $url[$i] +2);
                        }

                        $controller->{$url[1]}($params);
                    }
                    else{
                        // No tiene parámetros.
                        // Se manda a llamar el método tal cual.
                        $controller->{$url[1]}();
                    }
                }
                else{
                    // Error, no existe el método.
                    $controller = new Errores();
                }
            }
            else{
                // No hay método a cargar, se carga el método por default
                $controller->render();
            }
        }
        else{
            // No existe el archivo, manda error.
            $controller = new Errores();
        }


    }
}

?>
```

Carga el login bien, intento cargar la vista 404, que cuando el usuario escriba una URL que no existe, que lleve hasta esa vista 404 pero solo se queda la pantalla en blanco, aquí está mi archivo errores.php en la carpera errores

```
<?php

class Errores extends Controller{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        error_log('Errores::construct -> inicio de errores');
    }

    function render(){
        error_log('Errores::render -> Carga el index de errores');
        $this->view->render('errores/index');
    }
}

?>
```

Tengo un archivo de control de errores y no me manda ningún error, debería cargar la vista que cree que solo tiene un h1 con un mensaje que dice error 404 pero se queda la pantalla en blanco, el archivo de errores dice esto

```
[26-Apr-2023 21:49:27 Europe/Berlin] Inicio de aplicación web
[26-Apr-2023 21:49:28 Europe/Berlin] Errores::construct -> inicio de errores
```

Solo tiene unos mensajes que puse con error_log, pero como se ve, no sale el error log que está en la función render del archivo errores.php que mostré anteriormente, solo sale el de construct, lo que me da a entender que no me está leyendo esa función y por eso no me carga la vista, pero no sé por qué no la lee.

archivo controller.php en la carpera libs:

```
<?php

class Controller{
    function __construct(){
         $this->view = new View();
    }

    function loadModel($model){
        $url = 'models/'.$model.'model.php';
        
        if(file_exists($url)){
            require_once $url;

            $modelName = $model.'Model';
            $this->model = new $modelName();
        }
    }
}

?>
```

archivo view.php en la carpera libs:

```
<?php

class View{
    function __construct(){
        
    }

    function render($nombre, $data = []){
        $this->d = $data;

        require 'views/'.$nombre.'.php';
    }
}

?>
```

Quiero que salga la vista del archivo 404. Es esta, el archivo index.php en la carpeta errores de la carpeta vistas:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Error 404</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>ERROR 404</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Debería salir eso pero solo se ueda la pantalla en blanco

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en `app.php` en el 3er `else`, de abajo hacia arriba. Se está instanciando la clase `Errores`, pero no lo estás mandando al navegador. Falta ejecutar el método `render()`:

```php
else {
    // Error, no existe el método.
    $controller = new Errores();
    $controller->render(); # <-- Agregar esta línea
}
```

También la tienes que agregar en el último `else`.

En el [video en cuestión](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RpykWNiuBuk) (también tomé ese curso algún día), si ves en el minuto 5:53 está la línea que hace falta. Al parecer la agrega en algún momento fuera del video.

Comment: El curso está bueno para aprender conceptos, aunque hay cosas que se me hacen un tanto complicadas y tediosas. Pero en fin, para aprender todo es válido. Acá hay [otro curso](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dFfDJevrX6Y), sencillo pero muy bueno, que puedes usar para complementar.

Comment: GRACIAS GRACIAS ESO ERA MIL GRACIAS

Comment: Holaa @aeportugal hice otra pregunta referente a ese curso [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/594211/uso-php-y-mvc-y-no-me-carga-la-vista-de-signup). Por si me puedes ayudar, te lo agradecería <3