# Uso php y MVC y no me carga la vista de signup

Tags: php, mvc, model-view-controller

Quiero cargar la vista de signup de un sistema de un curso de vidamrr de PHP y MVC pero cuando cargo en la pantalla solo me sale en blanco y este texto:

```
 view->render('login/signup',[]); } } ?>
```

Imagino que es por la parte del código que puse que dice eso, en la carpeta controllers, el archivo signup.php:

```
<?

class Signup extends SessionController{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function render(){
        $this->view->render('login/signup',[]);
    }
    
}

?>
```

Debería salir esta vista, el archivo signup.php que está en la carpeta login dentro de la carpeta views, solo un h1 con un texto que dice Registro:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Registro</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <h1>Registro</h1>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Tengo un archivo de control de errores y me dice lo siguiente:

```
[20-May-2023 02:21:19 Europe/Berlin] Inicio de aplicación web
[20-May-2023 02:21:19 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'signup' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\MVC\libs\app.php:28
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\MVC\index.php(21): App->__construct()
#1 {main}
  thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\MVC\libs\app.php on line 28
```

Como se ve el primer error_log que puse lo carga bien, pero después me sale ese error. Este es mi archivo app.php en la carpeta libs:

```
<?php

require_once 'controllers/errores.php';

class App{
function __construct(){

    $url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : null;
    $url = rtrim($url, '/');
    $url = explode('/', $url);
    //http://localhost/MVC/user/updatePhoto -> user/updatePhoto

    if(empty ($url[0])){
        error_log('APP::construct-> no hay controlador especificado');
        $archivoController = 'controllers/login.php';
        require_once $archivoController;
        $controller = new Login();
        $controller->loadModel('login');
        $controller->render();
        return false;
    }

    $archivoController = 'controllers/'.$url[0].'.php';

    if(file_exists($archivoController)){
        require_once $archivoController;

        $controller = new $url[0];
        $controller->loadModel($url[0]);

        if(isset($url[1])){
            if(method_exists($controller, $url[1])){
                if(isset($url[2])){
                    // No de parámetros
                    $nparam = count($url) - 2;
                    // Arreglo de parámetros
                    $params = [];

                    for($i = 0; $i< $nparam; $i++){
                        array_push($params, $url[$i] +2);
                    }

                    $controller->{$url[1]}($params);
                }
                else{
                    // No tiene parámetros.
                    // Se manda a llamar el método tal cual.
                    $controller->{$url[1]}();
                }
            }
            else{
                // Error, no existe el método.
                $controller = new Errores();
                $controller->render();
            }
        }
        else{
            // No hay método a cargar, se carga el método por default
            $controller->render();
        }
    }
    else{
        // No existe el archivo, manda error.
        $controller = new Errores();
        $controller->render();
    }


}
}

?>
```

Mi archivo index.php:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('ignore_repeated_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_errors', FALSE);
ini_set('log_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('error_log', "C:/xampp/htdocs/MVC/php-error.log");
error_log("Inicio de aplicación web");

require_once 'libs/database.php';
require_once 'classes/errormessages.php';
require_once 'classes/successmessages.php';
require_once 'libs/controller.php';
require_once 'libs/model.php';
require_once 'libs/view.php';
require_once 'classes/sessioncontroller.php';
require_once 'libs/app.php';

require_once 'config/config.php';

$app = new App();

?>
```

Mi archivo usermodel.php en la carpeta models:

```
<?php

class UserModel extends Model implements IModel{
    private $id;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $role;
    private $budget;
    private $photo;
    private $name;
    
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        $this->username = '';
        $this->password = '';
        $this->role = '';
        $this->budget = 0.0;
        $this->photo = '';
        $this->name = '';
    }

    public function save(){
        try {
            $query = $this->prepare('INSERT INTO users(username, password, role, budget, photo, name) VALUES(:username, :password, :role, :budget, :photo, :name)');
            $query->execute([
                'username' => $this->username,
                'password' => $this->password,
                'role'     => $this->role,
                'budget'   => $this->budget,
                'photo'    => $this->photo,
                'name'     => $this->name
            ]);
            return true;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            error_log('USERMODEL::save->PDOException '. $e);
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function getAll(){
        $items = [];

        try {
            $query = $this->query('SELECT * FROM users');

            while ($p = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $item = new UserModel();
                $item->setId($p['id']);
                $item->setUsername($p['username']);
                $item->setPassword($p['password']);
                $item->setRole($p['role']);
                $item->setBudget($p['budget']);
                $item->setPhoto($p['photo']);
                $item->setName($p['name']);

                array_push($items, $item);
            }

            return $items;

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            error_log('USERMODEL::getAll->PDOException '. $e);
        }
    }

    public function get($id){
        try {
            $query = $this->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE  id = :id');
            $query->execute([
                'id' => $id
            ]);

            $user = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                $this->setId($user['id']);                
                $this->setUsername($user['username']);
                $this->setPassword($user['password']);
                $this->setRole($user['role']);
                $this->setBudget($user['budget']);
                $this->setPhoto($user['photo']);
                $this->setName($user['name']);

            return $this;

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            error_log('USERMODEL::getId->PDOException '. $e);
        }
    }

    public function delete($id){
        try {
            $query = $this->prepare('DELETE FROM users WHERE  id = :id');
            $query->execute([
                'id' => $id
            ]);

            return true;

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            error_log('USERMODEL::delete->PDOException '. $e);

            return false;
        }
    }

    public function update(){
        try {
            $query = $this->prepare('UPDATE users SET username = :username, password = :password, budget = :budget, photo = :photo, name = :name WHERE  id = :id');
            $query->execute([
                'id'       => $this->id,
                'username' => $this->username,
                'password' => $this->password,
                'budget'   => $this->budget,
                'photo'    => $this->photo,
                'name'     => $this->name
            ]);

            return true;

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            error_log('USERMODEL::update->PDOException '. $e);

            return false;
        }
    }

    public function from($array){
        $this->id       = $array['id'];
        $this->username = $array['username'];
        $this->password = $array['password'];
        $this->budget   = $array['budget'];
        $this->photo    = $array['photo'];
        $this->name     = $array['name'];
        $this->role     = $array['role'];
    }

    // Comprobar si ya existe un usuario
    public function exists(){

        try {
            $query = $this->prepare('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :username');
            $query->execute(['username' => $username]);

            if($query->rowCount() > 0){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            error_log('USERMODEL::exists->PDOException '. $e);
            return false;
        }

    }

    // Comparar contraseñas
    public function comparePasswords($password,$id){
        try {
            
            $user = $this->get($id);

            return password_verify($password,$user->getPassword());

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            error_log('USERMODEL::exists->PDOException '. $e);
            return false;
        }
    }

    private function getHashedPassword(){
        return password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, ['cost' => 10]);
    }

    public function setId($id){ $this->id = $id;}
    public function setRole($role){ $this->role = $role;}
    public function setBudget($budget){ $this->budget = $budget;}
    public function setPhoto($photo){ $this->photo = $photo;}
    public function setName($name){ $this->name = $name;}
    public function setUsername($username){ $this->username = $username;}
    public function setPassword($password){
        $this->password = $this->getHashedPassword($password);
    }

    public function getId(){ return $this->id;}
    public function getUsername(){ return $this->username;}
    public function getPassword(){ return $this->password;}
    public function getRole(){ return $this->role;}
    public function getBudget(){ return $this->budget;}
    public function getPhoto(){ return $this->photo;}
    public function getName(){ return $this->name;}

}






?>
```

Mi archivo view.php en la carpeta libs:

```
<?php

class View{
    function __construct(){
        
    }

    function render($nombre, $data = []){
        $this->d = $data;

        $this->handleMessages();

        require 'views/'.$nombre.'.php';
    }

    private function handleMessages(){
        if(isset($_GET['success']) && isset($_GET['error'])){
            // error, no puede existir un error y un success al mismo tiempo
        }
        else if(isset($_GET['success'])){
            $this->handleSuccess();  
        }
        else if(isset($_GET['error'])){
            $this->handleError();  
        }
    }

    private function handleError(){
        $hash = $_GET['error'];
        $error = new ErrorMessages();

        if($error->existsKey($hash)){
            $this->d['error'] = $error->get($hash);
        }
    }

    private function handleSuccess(){
        $hash = $_GET['success'];
        $success = new SuccessMessages();

        if($success->existsKey($hash)){
            $this->d['success'] = $success->get($hash);
        }
    }

    public function showMessages(){
        $this->showErrors();
        $this->showSuccess();
    }

    public function showErrors(){
        if(array_key_exists('error',$this->d)){
            echo '<div class="error">'.$this->d['error'].'</div>';
        }
    }

    public function showSuccess(){
        if(array_key_exists('success',$this->d)){
            echo '<div class="success">'.$this->d['success'].'</div>';
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Mi archivo session.php en la carpeta clases:

```
<?php

class Session{

    private $sessionName = 'user';

    public function __construct(){

        // Si no tiene una sessión, se inicia, y si ya la tiene, se omite esa parte
        if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE){
            session_start();
        }
        
    }

    public function setCurrentUser($user){
        $_SESSION[$this->sessionName] = $user;
    }

    public function getCurrentUser(){
        return $_SESSION[$this->sessionName];
    }

    public function closeSession(){
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
    }

    public function exists(){
        return isset($_SESSION[$this->sessionName]);
    }
    
}


?>
```

Mi archivo sessioncontroller.php en la carpeta classes:

```
<?php

require_once 'classes/session.php';

class SessionController extends Controller{
    private $userSession;
    private $username;
    private $userid;

    private $session;
    private $sites;

    private $user;

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->init();
    }

    function init(){
        $this->session = new Session();

        $json = $this->getJSONFileConfig();

        $this->sites = $json['sites'];
        $this->defaultSites = $json['default-sites'];

        $this->validateSession();
    }

    private function getJSONFileConfig(){
        $string = file_get_contents('config/access.json');
        $json = json_decode($string, true);

        return $json;
    }

    public function validateSession(){
        error_log('SESSIONCONTROLLER::validateSession');

        // Si existe la sesión
        if($this->existsSession()){
            $role = $this->getUserSessionData()->getRole();

            // Si la página a entrar es pública
            if($this->isPublic()){
                $this->redirectDefaultSiteByRole($role);
            }
            else{
                if($this->isAuthorized($role)){
                    // Puede pasar
                }
                else{
                    $this->redirectDefaultSiteByRole($role);
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            // No existe la sessión
            if($this->isPublic()){
                // No pasa nada, puede pasar
            }
            else{
                header('Location: '. constant('URL'). '');
            }
        }
    }

    function existsSession(){
        if(!$this->session->exists()) return false;
        if($this->session->getCurrentUser() == NULL) return false;

        $userid = $this->session->getCurrentUser();

        if($userid) return true;

        return false;
    }

    function getUserSessionData(){
        $id = $this->userid;
        $this->user = new UserModel();
        $this->user->get($id);

        error_log('SESSIONCONTROLLER::getUserSessionData -> '.$this->user->getUserName());

        return $this->user;
    }

    function isPublic(){
        $currentURL = $this->getCurrentPage();
        $currentURL = preg_replace("/\?.*/","",$currentURL);

        for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($this->sites); $i++){
            if($currentURL == $this->sites[$i]['site'] && $this->sites[$i]['access'] == 'public'){
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    function getCurrentPage(){
        $actualLink = trim("$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]");
        $url = explode('/',$actualLink);

        error_log('SESSIONCONTROLLER::getCurrentPage -> '.$url[2]);

        return $url[2];
    }

    private function redirectDefaultSiteByRole($role){
        $url = '';

        for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($this->sites); $i++){
            if($this->sites[$i]['role'] == $role){
                $url = '/MVC/'.$this->sites[$i]['sites'];
                break;
            }
        }

        header('location:'.$url);
    }

    private function isAuthorized($role){
        $currentURL = $this->getCurrentPage();
        $currentURL = preg_replace("/\?.*/","",$currentURL);

        for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($this->sites); $i++){
            if($currentURL == $this->sites[$i]['site'] && $this->sites[$i]['role'] == $role){
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    function initialize($user){
        $this->session->setCurrentUser($user->getId());
        $this->authorizeAccess($user->getRole());
    }

    function authorizeAccess($role){
        switch ($role) {
            case 'user': $this->redirect($this->defaultSites['user'],[]); break;
            case 'admin': $this->redirect($this->defaultSites['admin'],[]); break;
        }
    }

    function logout(){
        $this->session->closeSession();
    }
}

?>
```

Tengo otros archivos pero creo que el error debe estar los primeros que pasé. Gracias.

Comment: Hola. Parece que no está encontrando tus clases. Te recomendaría que uses [Autoloader](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.autoload.php), así, evitas llenar el código de `require` o de `include` por todos lados y errores de archivos no encontrados como en este caso.

Comment: @A.Cedano Gracias pero necesito solucionar ese error sin el spl_autoload_register() ¿O me puedes decir en qué parte coloco ese código? porfa, gracias

Comment: Decirte cómo implementar Autoloader es complicado sin saber la lógica que estás siguiendo para organizar el código, si usas o no PSR, etc. Viendo que intentas usar MVC, [te dejo aquí un ejemplo](https://github.com/daveh/php-mvc) que usa MVC y usa Autoloader. He implementado ese estilo y ahora que empiezo a migrar la App a Symfony todo es más simple porque usa un estilo muy parecido a ese potente Framework. En cuanto al error concreto aquí, para solucionarlo, mientras implementas algo más limpio, simplemente depura, siguiendo varios puntos del código. El error es claro: no encuentra la clase.

Answer (score 0):

El error se debe a que estás usando la notación `<?` en el archivo **signup.php**. Es desaconsejado el uso de esta etiqueta corta, la cual por defecto está deshabilitada en `php.ini`, [ver documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php#language.basic-syntax.phptags).

El problema se arregla poniendo la etiqueta de inicio `<?php`, como debe ser.

```php
<?php // <-- colocar etiqueta completa

class Signup extends SessionController{

    function __construct(){
        ...
```

Comment: GRACIAS MIL GRACIAS GRACIAS GRACIAS GRACIAS

Comment: Chico tengo otra pregunta con respecto a ese curso [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/594446/utilizo-php-y-mvc-y-no-registra-a-los-usuarios-ni-carga-la-p%c3%a1gina) :( Cualquier ayuda cuenta, gracias <3