# Utilizo PHP y MVC y no registra a los usuarios ni carga la página

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mvc, model-view-controller

Esta la es la 3ra preguta que hago aquí respecto a este sistema que estoy haciendo, gracias a las personas que se tomas el tiempo de responderme, aquí mi problema:

Estoy intentando registrar a los usuarios, aquí mi archivo signup.php en la carpeta controllers:

```
<?php

require_once 'models/usermodel.php';

class Signup extends SessionController{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function render(){
        $this->view->render('login/signup',[]);
    }
    
    function newUser(){
        if($this->existPOST(['username','password'])){

            $username =  $this->getPost('username');
            $password =  $this->getPost('password');

            if($username == '' ||  empty($username) || $password == '' ||  empty($password)){
                $this->redirect('signup',['error' => ErrorMessages::ERROR_SIGNUP_NEWUSER_EMPTY]);
            }

            $user = new UserModel();
            $user->setUsername($username);
            $user->setPassword($Password);
            $user->setRole('user');

            if($user->exists($username)){
                $this->redirect('signup',['error' => ErrorMessages::ERROR_SIGNUP_NEWUSER_EXISTS]);
            }
            else if($user->save()){
                $this->redirect('',['success' => SuccessMessages::SUCCESS_SIGNUP_NEWUSER]);
            }
            else{
                $this->redirect('signup',['error' => ErrorMessages::ERROR_SIGNUP_NEWUSER]);
            }

        }
        else{
            $this->redirect('signup',['error' => ErrorMessages::ERROR_SIGNUP_NEWUSER]);
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Se ve que al principio sale esta línea de código

```
 require_once 'models/usermodel.php';
```

Si la quito, sí sale esta vista signup.php en la carpeta login, dentro de la carpeta views:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Registro</title>
</head>
<body>

    <?php $this->showMessages(); ?>

    <form action="<?php echo constant('URL'); ?>/signup/newUser" method="POST">
        <h2>Registrarse</h2>
        <p>
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Registrarse">
        </p>
        <p>
            ¿Ya estás registrado? <a href="<?php echo constant('URL'); ?>">Iniciar sesión</a>
        </p>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Pero al darle en el botón de registrar se queda la pantalla de blanco y sale este error:

```
[23-May-2023 02:14:33 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'UserModel' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\MVC\controllers\signup.php:25
```

Entonces, si pongo la línea de código en el principio que incluye la clase UserModel para que la pueda leer, como se puede apreciar en el código que mostré anteriormente, entonces salen todas las páginas en blanco, no se ve nada y en el archivo de errores me sale esto:

```
[23-May-2023 02:39:46 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'IModel' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\MVC\models\usermodel.php on line 5
```

Este es mi archivo usermodel.php en la carpeta models:

```
<?php

include_once 'libs/imodel.php';

class UserModel extends Model implements IModel{
    private $id;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $role;
    private $budget;
    private $photo;
    private $name;
    
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        $this->username = '';
        $this->password = '';
        $this->role = '';
        $this->budget = 0.0;
        $this->photo = '';
        $this->name = '';
    }

    public function save(){
        try {
            $query = $this->prepare('INSERT INTO users(username, password, role, budget, photo, name) VALUES(:username, :password, :role, :budget, :photo, :name)');
            $query->execute([
                'username' => $this->username,
                'password' => $this->password,
                'role'     => $this->role,
                'budget'   => $this->budget,
                'photo'    => $this->photo,
                'name'     => $this->name
            ]);
            return true;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            error_log('USERMODEL::save->PDOException '. $e);
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function getAll(){
        $items = [];

        try {
            $query = $this->query('SELECT * FROM users');

            while ($p = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $item = new UserModel();
                $item->setId($p['id']);
                $item->setUsername($p['username']);
                $item->setPassword($p['password']);
                $item->setRole($p['role']);
                $item->setBudget($p['budget']);
                $item->setPhoto($p['photo']);
                $item->setName($p['name']);

                array_push($items, $item);
            }

            return $items;

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            error_log('USERMODEL::getAll->PDOException '. $e);
        }
    }

    public function get($id){
        try {
            $query = $this->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE  id = :id');
            $query->execute([
                'id' => $id
            ]);

            $user = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                $this->setId($user['id']);                
                $this->setUsername($user['username']);
                $this->setPassword($user['password']);
                $this->setRole($user['role']);
                $this->setBudget($user['budget']);
                $this->setPhoto($user['photo']);
                $this->setName($user['name']);

            return $this;

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            error_log('USERMODEL::getId->PDOException '. $e);
        }
    }

    public function delete($id){
        try {
            $query = $this->prepare('DELETE FROM users WHERE  id = :id');
            $query->execute([
                'id' => $id
            ]);

            return true;

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            error_log('USERMODEL::delete->PDOException '. $e);

            return false;
        }
    }

    public function update(){
        try {
            $query = $this->prepare('UPDATE users SET username = :username, password = :password, budget = :budget, photo = :photo, name = :name WHERE  id = :id');
            $query->execute([
                'id'       => $this->id,
                'username' => $this->username,
                'password' => $this->password,
                'budget'   => $this->budget,
                'photo'    => $this->photo,
                'name'     => $this->name
            ]);

            return true;

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            error_log('USERMODEL::update->PDOException '. $e);

            return false;
        }
    }

    public function from($array){
        $this->id       = $array['id'];
        $this->username = $array['username'];
        $this->password = $array['password'];
        $this->budget   = $array['budget'];
        $this->photo    = $array['photo'];
        $this->name     = $array['name'];
        $this->role     = $array['role'];
    }

    // Comprobar si ya existe un usuario
    public function exists(){

        try {
            $query = $this->prepare('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :username');
            $query->execute(['username' => $username]);

            if($query->rowCount() > 0){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            error_log('USERMODEL::exists->PDOException '. $e);
            return false;
        }

    }

    // Comparar contraseñas
    public function comparePasswords($password,$id){
        try {
            
            $user = $this->get($id);

            return password_verify($password,$user->getPassword());

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            error_log('USERMODEL::exists->PDOException '. $e);
            return false;
        }
    }

    private function getHashedPassword(){
        return password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, ['cost' => 10]);
    }

    public function setId($id){ $this->id = $id;}
    public function setRole($role){ $this->role = $role;}
    public function setBudget($budget){ $this->budget = $budget;}
    public function setPhoto($photo){ $this->photo = $photo;}
    public function setName($name){ $this->name = $name;}
    public function setUsername($username){ $this->username = $username;}
    public function setPassword($password){
        $this->password = $this->getHashedPassword($password);
    }

    public function getId(){ return $this->id;}
    public function getUsername(){ return $this->username;}
    public function getPassword(){ return $this->password;}
    public function getRole(){ return $this->role;}
    public function getBudget(){ return $this->budget;}
    public function getPhoto(){ return $this->photo;}
    public function getName(){ return $this->name;}

}






?>
```

Mi archivo model en la carpeta libs:

```
<?php

include_once 'libs/imodel.php';

class Model{
    function __construct(){
        $this->db = new Database();
    }

    function query($query){
        return $this->db->connect()->query($query);
    }

    function prepare($query){
        return $this->db->connect()->prepare($query);
    }
}

?>
```

Mi archivo index.php fuera de todas las carpetas:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('ignore_repeated_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_errors', FALSE);
ini_set('log_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('error_log', "C:/xampp/htdocs/MVC/php-error.log");
error_log("Inicio de aplicación web");

require_once 'libs/database.php';
require_once 'classes/errormessages.php';
require_once 'classes/successmessages.php';
require_once 'libs/controller.php';
require_once 'libs/model.php';
require_once 'libs/view.php';
require_once 'classes/sessioncontroller.php';
require_once 'libs/app.php';

require_once 'config/config.php';

$app = new App();

?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito que se vean todas las páginas y poder registrar a los usuarios.

Comment: Hola. Muestra tu árbol de directorios y la ubicación de los archivos implicados en este problema.

Comment: Listo amigo @A.Cedano , creo que te refieres a eso, en caso de que no sea avísame porfa

Comment: Exacto, el problema es que debes retroceder un directorio para que vuelva al directorio que contiene a `models`, algo así: **`require_once '../models/usermodel.php';`** Si no retrocedes, anteponiendo `../`, dado que haces el require desde `controllers`, lo que interpreta es: *busca la carpeta `models` aquí donde estamos (en `controllers`)* y por eso no la encuentra.

Comment: También aquí: `include_once 'libs/imodel.php';` cometes el mismo error. `libs` está en el  mismo directorio padre de `models`, de modo que debes volver al directorio padre para que encuentre el archivo: **`include_once '../libs/imodel.php';`** De todos modos, esto de poner rutas así a mano no es una buena idea. Deberías considerar el uso de Autoloader, requiere una simple configuración. Si ahora no puedes dedicarte a ello (tampoco tardarás más de media hora) puedes al menos definir todas tus rutas en constantes. Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/91541/29967).